# Attaching a hidden text field to a form MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

This very well may end up being a very silly question in a way but basically I have this "form" in a model that gets attached to my View as the form but I haven't been able to actually pass any data do it from the View.  It only has two properties: an Id property and a String property.  I've been trying to fill the String property with text from a hidden text box on the page with no luck.

Form code:

```
    public class AllocateListForm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string HiddenText { get; set; }
}
```

Relevant View code:

```
  <% using (Html.BeginForm("SaveExit", "User", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "selectExitPoints" }))  { %>
    <fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" id="HiddenText" />
    </fieldset>
  <% } %>
```

There is JQuery behind the scenes that fills `HiddenText` with text and I can assure you that it is filling.  There is also JQuery behind the scenes that performs an Ajax submission and I can promise you that code works as it is used elsewhere in the application without a problem.  When I perform the action that submits the form to the server and I go to my controller code that this points to, I have a breakpoint set so I can go into the console and check if the HiddenText field on the form has any data it is null.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you assign the input's name to be "HiddenText" the model binder should pick it up. I'm assuming that your controller action accepts an `AllocateListForm` as a parameter.

```
<input type="hidden" name="HiddenText" id="HiddenText" />
```

You can also use Html Helpers like so:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HiddenText, new { id = "HiddenText" })
```

EDIT: Add an AllocateListForm as a property of your main model and then change the helper to be `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyAllocateListForm.HiddenText)`

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  It is `public JsonResult SaveExit(AllocateListForm exitListForm)` so in the console I was checking `? exitListForm.HiddenText`.  However I cannot use an HTML helper as my Model does not have a property for HiddenText, only the form does.

Comment: @Jared Is your view strongly typed to a different model? Sounds like you should create a viewmodel to be able to access form properties more easily.

Comment: It is strongly typed to a different model, I guess I was just looking for the simplest way to do this.  This page is very simple, it just presents the user with a list of checkboxes and allows them to check and uncheck from the list, then the hidden field is filled with their selection(s) to be passed into the controller.

Comment: So add an `AllocateListForm` as a property of your main model and then change the helper to be `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyAllocateListForm.HiddenText)`

Comment: Ahhhhh, I'll give that a go.  Would that be the same as `<%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Form.HiddenText, new { @id = "HiddenText" })%>?

Comment: I'd think so (sorry, I assumed you were using Razor, which was stupid of me).

Comment: Not at all, I'm quite sure its the same anyways as if I don't have `x.Form.HiddenText` typed correctly (i.e. `x.Form.HidddddenText`) to match the proper path and property name I get a compilation error for that line.  So thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick, if you want to do it the Razor-way.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HiddenText);
```

Comment: I can't use HTML helpers as my Model doesn't have a field for HiddenText, only the form does.

Comment: So, if I was to write '@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RegUserID, new { id = "HiddenText" })' how would I set the value for model.RegUserID?